# PHP load XML on static IP-address

Tags: php, xml, static, ip

I want to print out de data from a XML that's on a static IP-address.

Here you can see the XML (it's an example):
http://216.160.239.63:9011/stateFull.xml

And my code:

```
$xml=simplexml_load_file("http://216.160.239.63:9011/stateFull.xml") or die("Error: Cannot create object");
print_r($xml);
```

Can anyone tel me why it isn't working? I can see the XML in my browser when I type the url in the adress bar, but I can't print it out by PHP script and use the data.

Is there maybe another script that can read out xml data that's on a static IP-address??

Hope somebody can help me out. I googled and tried for so long....

Comment: Your code is missing.

Comment: <?php
$xml=simplexml_load_file("http://216.160.239.63:9011/stateFull.xml") or die("Error: Cannot create object");
print_r($xml);
?>

Comment: Define 'it isn't working'. Do you get any output? You use the code like in your question, with http:// before the ip adres?

Comment: There's nothing in my output on screen. No output. When I use anothet online xml file in my code it gives a normal output. 

Isn't it possible to use an ip-adres in php code or something?

Comment: I use the code with http://. I also tried it without, but this give no result also. And my output on screen = "Error: Cannot create object"

Comment: That isn't the problem, I copied your code and I get output on my screen. Maybe compare the xml file that does work with your own. Could be something missing. Or do you have some kind of port blocking in your network?

Comment: O really, you get output....how can I check port blocking??

Comment: Try to load it with `file_get_contents()`. Ask the owner of server/file if he requires special HTTP headers.